# How to have a variable with generic typing and multiple inheritance in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I have this Protocol, Class, and a Class that takes a generic which has to conform to both.

I want to build a registry which holds an array of such classes, but how do I define a variable in the registry which will satisfy the compiler?

Consider this example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

}

class SomeClass {

}

class AnotherClass<R, P where P:SomeProtocol, P:SomeClass> {

}

class Registry {

    private init() {}

    // This is not allowed since the second generic doesn't conform to neither required class
    var registry:[AnotherClass<AnyObject, AnyObject>] = [] 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how

```
import UIKit
protocol SomeProtocol {

}

class SomeClass {

}

class AnotherClass<R, P where P:SomeProtocol, P:SomeClass> {

}

class TheClass : SomeClass, SomeProtocol {}

class Registry {

    private init() {}

    var registry:[AnotherClass<AnyObject, TheClass>] = []

}
```

You need to define a class that inherits `SomeClass` and `SomeProtocol`. `AnyObject` doesn't inherit from `SomeClass` and `SomeProtocol` and that's why you get an error.

**Update**
To make it less restritive

This is how

```
import UIKit
protocol SomeProtocol {

}

class SomeClass {

}

class AnotherClass<R, P where P:SomeProtocol, P:SomeClass> {

}

class TheClass : SomeClass, SomeProtocol {}

class Registry<T, where T:SomeProtocol, T:SomeClass> {

    private init() {}

    var registry:[AnotherClass<AnyObject, T>] = []

}
```

**Update 2**

Eventually, however, you will end up with something like

```
Registry<TheClass>
```

because generics needs a concrete class in the end.

What you could do is enforce the type at runtime instead - you will need to add `@objc` to your protocols though - via `is`. An alternative would be to scrap generics and use a interface or a base class.

Comment: Wouldn't this making the solution more specific than required? You can define the use of multiple everywhere but here? Isn't that odd?

Comment: @KevinR You're right. This is more restrictive that the idea that you expressed.

Comment: Then we have to make Registry a generic class as well. I have update my answer with an example.

Comment: But that would mean you'll have a problem upon initialing the Registry?

Comment: Because of the static type checking you have to have a class that's inherits SomeProtocol and SomeClass. You can keep pushing this problem up the chain by making whatever it calls generic. But eventually you'll need a class, whether it's a base class or a proxy class that supports it. An alternative is to just use interfaces.

Comment: Thats why I don't want to push it up the chain, but find a way to describe it in the var itself instead of wrapping it :)

Comment: The only way to do that is create a base class or a wrapper class.

Comment: I know a generic needs to be a specific class in the end, but it's not strange to want to define a list of classes that adhere a protocol, instead of being specific at that point.

Comment: If you want an array of protocols then just make `registry`,  `var registry:[SomeProtocol] = []`